# Advanced Reporting Extension Error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, extensions

I have installed the Advanced Reporting extension for Magento 2. When I enable it I am getting errors. I did the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

On my site I'm getting the error:

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Execption\LocalException): Please upgrade database: Run: "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.

My terminal gives me the error:

> [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception] SQLSTATE[HY000] General Error: 1419: You do not have SUPER privileges

and

> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] General Error: 1419: You do not have SUPER privileges

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by setting the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` MySQL option to 1.

Visit this website for more info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_bin_trust_function_creators

You can set this up directly in MySQL client:

```
set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
```

If you can't change this setting, speak to your hosting provider.

You can also try the following:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p
set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
```

Comment: I ran the command and then reran all the other commands and still get the same error

Comment: What MySQL client are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.7

Comment: Are you using PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: No i have setup a local Db

Comment: You have successfully changed the config of `log_bin_trust_function_creators` to `1`?

Comment: Not yet, I am having issues with my mysql creds

Comment: I fixed it. I had to go into my database and add the data version to the table.

Comment: ahhh great! Finally you got it :)

Answer (score 0):

I found in my database that the data version was missing. I filled it in with same version as the version schema and then ran the install commands again, cleared the cache and the extension installed successfully with no errors.